# Can ping server but no telnet or www

Tags: networking, nas, tcpip, remote-access, telnet

I have a NAS (Iomega home media 1TB) connected to a router with a 1Gb ethernet cable.
Occasionally I lose access to it; when this happens I can still ping it by it's static IP or scan it with Nmap but I can't telnet to it and the HTTP server doesn't respond.

It's running Debian 5.0, with an ARM processor, and no iptables.

Comment: What do you have to do to regain access? what's the usual scenario for losing access? Does it fail to respond under actual use, or after it's been idle for a while?

Comment: I have to reboot to make it works again. After some amount of time is just disappear from network. not sure if someone uses it (there is smb daemon running), maybe after some idle period.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic symptom of duplicate IP addresses. Especially if the problem seems to come and go randomly. The 2nd device might answer a ping, but won't have the services you expect. Is there anything else on the network? Does the static IP overlap with a range issued by DHCP?

Comment: router give 192.168.1.100-149, but nas has static ip 192.168.1.33, also nmap shows all ports usually opened on nas (telnet, www etc) other computers doesn't have.